# For which $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ is this function integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functional-analysis

Let $T>0$. As an exercise, I need to find all the values of $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\int_0^T \frac{1}{|x|^{\alpha}} dx$$
is Lebesgue integrable.

I know how to prove that the function $1/x$ is not integrable in $(0, 1]$ (by applying monotone convergence to a suitable sequence), but I have no idea how to proceed with this exercise. I would apply the same idea in this case, but I don't know and if it works.

Could someone please help me?

Thank you indvance!

Comment: I see two versions of this same question. I don't know why this is the case, but you may want to delete one of the two :)

Comment: I think it does not answer my question because the integral in the question you posted it between  $1$ and $\infty$, mine is between $0$ and $T$.

Comment: @QuantumSpace it is the same if I consider $1/x$ and $1/ |x|$? Sorry

Comment: @C.Bishop Yes because you integrate over $[0,T]$...

Comment: @C.Bishop the link I gave shows the solution to your problem when $T=1$ which is enough to answer your question. FIY it also explains how to relate your problem to the integration on $(1,\infty)$. Anyway you should always search for an answer already posted on the forum before to ask a question. One guideline of this website is to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Changing the upper bound on the integral doesn't matter so much as long as it's finite. You might be interested in when the domain is $\mathbb{R}^n$. In this case, you use generalizations of polar/spherical coordinates, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3393709/determine-parameters-in-which-the-function-belong-to-space-lpΩ/3393745#3393745

Answer (score 1):

You know that $\frac{1}{x^\alpha}$ is measurable on $(0,T]$, I  guess?

In case you don't, this follows from the monotone convergence theorem for Lebesgue integration. One way to go about this is to define $f_n(x) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  0  & \mbox{if } 0<x<\frac{1}{2^n} \\
  \frac{1}{x^\alpha} & \mbox{if } \frac{1}{2^n}\leq x\leq T
 \end{array}
\right.$

Then to find out whether it's integrable is only a matter of computing the integral and checking if it is finite or infinite.